# why printf cannot work properly in openMP's omp for?

Tags: printf, openmp

I run the code below using Clion with WSL.

```cpp
#include <cstdio>
#include <omp.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int chunk = 6;
    omp_set_num_threads(4);

#pragma omp parallel default(none) firstprivate(chunk)
    {
        int thread_id = omp_get_thread_num();
#pragma omp for schedule(static, chunk)
        for (int i = 0; i < 24; ++i) {
            printf("Thread %d is processing iteration %d\n", thread_id, i);

        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is the output of the code:

```
Thread 2 is processing iteration 12
Thread 0 is processing iteration 0
Thread 0 is processing iteration 1
Thread 0 is processing iteration 2
Thread 0 is processing iteration 3
Thread 0 is processing iteration 4
Thread 0 is processing iteration 5
Thread 1 is processing iteration 6
Thread 1 is processing iteration 7
Thread 1 is processing iteration 8
Thread 1 is processing iteration 9
Thread 1 is processing iteration 10
Thread 1 is processing iteration 11
Thread 3 is processing iteration 18
Thread 3 is processing iteration 19
Thread 3 is processing iteration 20
Thread 3 is processing iteration 21
Thread 3 is processing iteration 22
Thread 3 is processing iteration 23

Process finished with exit code 020
Thread 3 is processing iteration 21
Thread 3 is processing iteration 22
Thread 3 is processing iteration 23
```

## My question

1. Why is there no complete data for thread 2 here?
2. Why do some of the data in thread3 appear repeatedly?
3. Why do non zero exit codes appear?

**Thank you for your help!!!**

I run the code many times.
I searched,but got no answear.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem on WSL with both Clang and GCC : everything works well on my machine. Please share information about the environment and the command line used to build the target program. I seems your compiler or OpenMP tool chain is bogus. That being said, I wonder if using a chunk size `chunk` which is a first-private variable is legit. I expect chunk to be a global/shared constant (possibly even a compile-time one). If it is different in each threads, I do not expect the static scheduling to be the same.

Comment: Non-zero exit codes mean that there is an issue (e.g. crash due to an assertion violation).

Comment: Just a guess but I'd say that the version of `printf` you're using is not thread-safe. I know that is totally  killing any form of parallelism here, but for the sake of testing, try protecting it with a `#pragma omp critical`.